# Materia Ui React Tabs

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I'm using [material UI tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/) in React.
When I write and fill a text field and then switch between tabs, the text field becomes empty. Can anyone help me please, and give me an example?

Comment: Issue here is you are not storing the value to `state` ( if using class component ). show the code block or give a stackblitz  example, so we can give a good solution.

Comment: Added a link, fixed grammar and typos.